# installed libtool but libtoolize not found

Tags: macos, libxml2, autotools, autoconf, libtool

i'm trying to build `libxml2` from source on my mac.

so i have `autoconf`, `libtool`, and `automake` installed using [macports](https://macports.org/)

`autoconf` and `automake` seem to be working fine as expected.

i try running `autogen.sh` first.

`libtoolize --version` unfortunately gives

```
-bash: libtoolize: command not found
```

i try running (again)

```
sudo port install libtool

--->  Cleaning libtool
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

i try

```
locate libtool
```

and it seems to be installed fine

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man/man1/libtool.1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/libtool
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man/man1/libtool.1
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/cross/mipsel-linux-binutils/files/110-uclibc-libtool-conf.patch
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libtool
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libtool/Portfile
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libtool/files
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libtool/files/ltmain.m4sh-allow-clang-stdlib.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libtool-devel
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/libtool-devel/Portfile
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/openslp/files/libtool-tags.patch
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/t1lib/files/patch-libtool-tag.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/print/pdflib/files/patch-libtool.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/security/steghide/files/libtool-tag.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/www/apache2/files/libtool-tag.diff
/usr/bin/libtool
/usr/lib/php/build/libtool.m4
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool
/usr/share/man/man1/libtool.1
```

how do i get `libtoolize` to work?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You typically need to use `glibtool` and `glibtoolize`, since `libtool` already exists on OS X as a binary tool for creating Mach-O dynamic libraries. So, that's how MacPorts installs it, using a program name transform, though the port itself is still named 'libtool'.

Some `autogen.sh` scripts (or their equivalent) will honor the `LIBTOOL` / `LIBTOOLIZE` environment variables. I have a line in my own `autogen.sh` scripts:

```
case `uname` in Darwin*) glibtoolize --copy ;;
  *) libtoolize --copy ;; esac
```

You may or may not want the `--copy` flag.

---

Note: If you've installed the autotools using MacPorts, a correctly written `configure.ac` with `Makefile.am` files should only require `autoreconf -fvi`. It should call `glibtoolize`, etc., as expected. Otherwise, some packages will distribute an `autogen.sh` or similar script.

Comment: where is autogen.sh located typically?

Comment: @Erik - usually in the top-level directory, and included in the distribution by adding `EXTRA_DIST = autogen.sh` in the top-level `Makefile.am`. Sometimes it has a name like `bootstrap.sh`. Often, developers are happy with the defaults provided by `autoreconf`.

Comment: simply replacing `libtoolize` with `glibtoolize` worked for me

Answer (score 25):

I hope my answer is not too naive. I am a noob to OSX.

[brew](http://brew.sh/) install libtool solved a similar issue for me.

Comment: The formula (for those who may not want to use Homebrew but wouldn't mind some pointers) is [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libtool.rb)

Comment: If you've installed other tools like `imagemagick` you may discover the brew caveat:
    `In order to prevent conflicts with Apple's own libtool we have prepended a "g" so, you have instead: ` **glibtool** `and` **glibtoolize**

Comment: There's an issue when installing libtool with brew: you may get an error like "/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 406: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory". The solution that worked for me was 'brew unlink libtool' (this may not be necessary) and then 'brew uninstall libtool && brew install libtool' (ebothmann's comment at https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/43874).

Answer (score 22):

To bring together a few threads `libtoolize` is installed as `glibtoolize` when you install `libtool` using **brew**. This can be achieved as follows; install it and then create a softlink for libtoolize:

```
brew install libtool
ln -s /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize /usr/local/bin/libtoolize
```

Comment: Better use `ln -s $(which glibtoolize) /usr/local/bin/libtoolize`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Brew is to use `macports`. For example:

```
$ port info libtool
libtool @2.4.6_5 (devel, sysutils)
Variants:             universal

Description:          GNU libtool is a generic library support script. Libtool hides the complexity of using shared libraries behind a consistent, portable interface.
Homepage:             https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool

Build Dependencies:   xattr
Platforms:            darwin, freebsd
License:              libtool
Maintainers:          Email: larryv@macports.org, GitHub: larryv
```

Then like Brew, you do:

```
$ sudo port install libtool
Password:
--->  Fetching archive for libtool
--->  Attempting to fetch libtool-2.4.6_5.darwin_15.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/libtool
--->  Attempting to fetch libtool-2.4.6_5.darwin_15.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/libtool
--->  Installing libtool @2.4.6_5
--->  Activating libtool @2.4.6_5
--->  Cleaning libtool
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Updating database of C++ stdlib usage
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.                             
--->  No broken ports found.
```

Then you can check where it lives ... btw, you can soft-link glibtoolize to libtoolize. For my needs either was okay

```
$ which glibtoolize
/opt/local/bin/glibtoolize
```