# Libtool error installing osm2pgsql from source

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, libtool

I'm trying to install osm2pgsql from source on OSX Mavericks. I'm following the basic steps in the readme, but when I try running ./autogen.sh I'm getting a libtool error:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
Can't exec "libtoolize": No such file or directory at /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345,  line 4.
autoreconf: failed to run libtoolize: No such file or directory
autoreconf: libtoolize is needed because this package uses Libtool
```

I have installed all the dependencies, and have the latest versions of autoconf and automake. Can't figure out why it can't find libtoolize. If I run locate libtoolize I can see it's installed.

What's going on?

**Update**

As per suggestion in the first comment, I tried adding the following lines to the `autogen.sh` script:

```
case `uname` in Darwin*) glibtoolize --copy ;;
  *) libtoolize --copy ;; esac
```

This seems to get a little further, but still gets stuck. This is the output in Terminal:

```
$ ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
Can't exec "libtoolize": No such file or directory at /usr/local/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345,  line 4.
autoreconf: failed to run libtoolize: No such file or directory
autoreconf: libtoolize is needed because this package uses Libtool
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
glibtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Still no luck getting it to actually work yet...
Any help?

Comment: You will need to modify the `autogen.sh` script. `libtool` is usually installed as [glibtool and glibtoolize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448582/installed-libtool-but-libtoolize-not-found?rq=1) on OSX.

Comment: Any idea how it needs to be modified? The autogen.sh script only contains the following two lines: `#!/bin/sh
autoreconf -vfi`

Comment: I have altered the `autogen.sh` script as suggested in the question you linked, but it hasn't worked – see update above

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. backup your autogen.sh
2. delete the libtoolize/libtool check code in the autogen.sh, something like

(libtoolize --version) < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 || {
    ...
 }

1. replace with this :

gprefix=`which glibtoolize 2>&1 >/dev/null`
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
      glibtoolize --force
   else
      libtoolize --force
   fi

4.run autogen.sh again

Answer (score 0):

I had to add libtoolize to my $PATH in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/path/that/contains/libtoolize:$PATH
```

I found the path that contains libtoolize using `locate libtoolize`