# Mac OSX. Where can I download glibtool?

Tags: macos, autoconf, automake, libtool, watchman

I am trying to setup [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source) for the mac. As stated on the [website](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source), I need to install glibtool.

**Can anyone provide a link to where I can download glibtool?**

I need to be able to download it from its source and the only solution I can find is by using brew.

**I do not want to use brew.**

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason not to make life easy and use **homebrew**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glibtool` is "GNU Libtool".  It is typically installed as `libtool` on most systems, but because macOS has its own `libtool` that has completely different functionality, it is usually installed as `glibtool` on macOS.

If you can't directly use homebrew to install it, you can duplicate the steps in its recipe, which you can find here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/libtool.rb

For the sake of keeping this answer "working" even if homebrew goes away, the homepage for `libtool` is https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/ and you can follow the instructions there for information on how to build and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I've covered similar issues to Wez's answer from a [MacPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448582/installed-libtool-but-libtoolize-not-found/15448876#15448876) perspective; I'll go ahead and assume you can't use that either.

The latest stable version at this time is [2.4.6](http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.gz). Typical best practice is to make a directory, e.g., `build` in the top level of the source. Add the prefix: `g`, with `--program-prefix=g`, the top level installation directory `--prefix=PREFIX`, or specify more fine-grained installation directories options for `bin`, `include`, `lib`, and `share` directories.

```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> ../configure --prefix=/my/install/path --program-prefix=g
> make; make install
```

You now have `glibtool` and `glibtoolize` in `$PREFIX/bin`.